# Optimal strategy for choosing number of attempts

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem and I just keep getting stuck with seemingly unsolvable expressions. I would like to know if there is an easier way to look at this that I'm missing

Suppose a shooter wishes to shoot $n$ targets. Each bullet costs $b$ and he only succeeds with a probability $p$ in successfully hitting the target with a bullet. He goes to the store to buy bullets and each trip costs him $t$. The unused bullets after $n$ targets have been shot are overhead cost.

The shooter wants to minimize the cost to eliminate the target. So the question is, what is the optimal strategy for buying the bullets as a function of $n$. If it makes the problem easier, we can assume that $p = \frac{1}{2}$.

I've tried to solve the problem by trying th minimize the expected cost, $c(n)$ for $n$ targets if he buys $f(n) \geq n $ bullets on each trip. So the goal would be to find the funtional $f(n)$. I get a recursive expression based the number of remaining targets - but I cannot figure out a method to get a closed form solution. Does anybody know if this maps to a well known problem or have any ideas about how this can be solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $n=1$ and assume the optimal buy is $f(1)=m$ bullets. The his costs $c(1)$ will be $t+mb+ (1-p)^mc(1)$, i.e., 
$$ c(1)=\frac{t+mb}{1-(1-p)^m}$$
This is minimal when $$ b(1-(1-p)^m)-(t+mb)\ln(1-p)(1-p)^m\approx 0$$
(i.e., for $m$ obtained from the exact solution either rouned up or down). Already this simple specialcase is not trivial analytically. But for concrete values of $t$ and $b$, it is quite straightforward to determine $f(n)$ and $c(n)$ recursively